# Duvida Sobre sobre o usuário logado

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estive um tempo parado por falta de oportunidade de trabalho na minha região.
Agora fui convidado para participar de um projeto e já me deparei com um problema que pra mim esta complicado.

Preciso iniciar um campo com o nome do grupo e/ou 'unidade' este é o nome do campo que criei, ao qual o usuário logado pertence, criei uma classe pra definir e essa 'unidade' e estou tentando resgatar no meu form, o porblem aé que ta voltando vazio inicialmente concei cirando um função agora e por ultimo uma classe. o codigo agora esta dando resultado que é uma quary/property tipo   em capsulado ou retorna vazio quando uso a classe, meu codigo ficou assim:

estou usando Python3 e Django3

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unidade = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.unidade
```

forms.py

```
class get_origem(Employee):

    def user_logado(slef):
        return slef.user.is_authenticated()

    def get_origem(self, user_logado):
        usuario = User.objects.get(username=user_logado)
        grupo_unidade = usuario.employee.unidade

        if grupo_unidade == user_logado:
            self.grupo_unidade

        else:
            self.grupo_unidade = 'NAO PERTENCE AO GRUPO'

            return self.grupo_unidade

        return self.grupo_unidade

class Cadastro_Unico_Add_Form(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Cadastro_Unico_Add_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['hospital_de_origem'].initial = get_origem
```

a duvida é como fazer com que o resultado retorne o grupo ou unidade do usuário logado.

a outra forma que tentei foi essa:

```
@property
def user_logado():
    return request.user.is_authenticated()

@user_logado.getter
def get_origem():
    usuario = User.objects.get(username=user_logado)
    grupo_unidade = usuario.employee.unidade

    if usuario == get_origem:
        grupo_unidade

    else:
        grupo_unidade = 'NAO PERTENCE AO GRUPO'

    return grupo_unidade
```

Que me retorna isso:  `<property object at 0x7f2c84ddd470>`                                                 que creio ser o resultado encapsulado.

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar, fiz bastante pesquisa li na documentação do jango,  entendi que o @property  emcapsula os informações da classe, mas não acertei como mostrar estas informações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma certa dificuldade de acessar instancias da **request** dentro de forms, existem vários truques para isso.

Utilize a biblioteca django-globals, que te permite acessar o usuário e a request em qualquer lugar.

[django-globals](https://github.com/svetlyak40wt/django-globals/)

Quando for iniciar o form:

```
from django_globals import global

class Cadastro_Unico_Add_Form(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Cadastro_Unico_Add_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['hospital_de_origem'].initial = global.user.employee.unidade
```

Solução simples e limpa

Existe outras maneiras, uma discussão interessante: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057252/how-do-i-access-the-request-object-or-any-other-variable-in-a-forms-clean-met

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado! funcionou de primeira.

Comment: @MARCELOPEREIRADASILVA, Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 