# Form Django Carrega os Valores mas não Salva

Tags: python-3.x, django

**Pesquisei bastante o meu caso na internet e não encontrei uma resposta que encaixe no meu problema.**

Seguindo a dica do JACKSON MOURA nesse resposta que me deu em outro caso esse aqui: [Duvida Sobre sobre o usurário logado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/433775/duvida-sobre-sobre-o-usur%C3%A1rio-logado)

consegui montar o form pegando os dados do bando e iniciando preenchido como preciso que seja segue o codigo:

models.py

```
class CadastroDoPaciente(models.Model):

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sexo = models.ForeignKey(SexoDoPaciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nome_da_mae = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cartao_sus = models.BigIntegerField()
    data_nascimento = models.DateField()
    cpf = models.IntegerField()
    municipio = models.ForeignKey(Municipos, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    be = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class RegulacaoPaciente(models.Model):

    r_nome = models.ForeignKey(CadastroDoPaciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='r_nome', default='nome')
    r_sexo = models.ForeignKey(CadastroDoPaciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='r_sexo', default='sexo')
    r_cartao_sus = models.ForeignKey(CadastroDoPaciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='r_cartao_sus', default='cartao_sus')
    r_data_nascimento = models.ForeignKey(CadastroDoPaciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='r_data_nascimento', default='data_nascimento')
    r_cpf = models.ForeignKey(CadastroDoPaciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='r_cpf', default='cpf')
    r_municipio = models.ForeignKey(CadastroDoPaciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='r_municipio', default='municipio')
    r_be = models.ForeignKey(CadastroDoPaciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='r_be', default='be')
    cadastrarcartaosisreg = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hospital_de_origem = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hospital_de_destino = models.ForeignKey(Hospitais, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vincularlocomocaopaciente = models.ForeignKey(LocoMocaoPaciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reservadeleito = models.CharField(max_length=50)# criar status para em trasito / ocupado
    hospitalarinformarnumeroaih = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tipoveiculousado = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    observacoesgerais = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

forms.py

```
class Regulacao_Do_Paciente_Form(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(Regulacao_Do_Paciente_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['r_nome'].initial = str(self.instance.nome)
        self.fields['r_sexo'].initial = str(self.instance.sexo)
        self.fields['r_cartao_sus'].initial = str(self.instance.cartao_sus)
        self.fields['r_data_nascimento'].initial = str(self.instance.data_nascimento)
        self.fields['r_cpf'].initial = str(self.instance.cpf)
        self.fields['r_municipio'].initial = str(self.instance.municipio)
        self.fields['r_be'].initial = str(self.instance.be)
        self.fields['hospital_de_origem'].initial = globals.user.employee.unidade

    class Meta:
        model = RegulacaoPaciente

        fields = [
            'r_nome',
            'r_sexo',
            'r_cartao_sus',
            'r_data_nascimento',
            'r_cpf',
            'r_municipio',
            'r_be',
            'cadastrarcartaosisreg',
            'vincularlocomocaopaciente',
            'reservadeleito',
            'hospitalarinformarnumeroaih',
            'tipoveiculousado',
            'observacoesgerais',
            'hospital_de_origem',
            'hospital_de_destino',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'r_nome': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
            'r_sexo': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
            'r_cartao_sus': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
            'r_data_nascimento': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
            'r_cpf': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
            'r_municipio': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
            'r_be': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
            'cadastrarcartaosisreg': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
            'vincularlocomocaopaciente': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
            'reservadeleito': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
            'hospitalarinformarnumeroaih': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
            'tipoveiculousado': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
            'observacoesgerais': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
            'hospital_de_origem': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
            'hospital_de_destino': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': False}),
        }
```

views.py

```
class Regulacao_do_Pacinete_CreateViews(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView, UpdateView):
    form_class = Regulacao_Do_Paciente_Form
    model = CadastroDoPaciente    
    template_name = "principal/regulacao_do_paciente.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

Resultado do Codigo:[image: Resultado esperado]

quando clico em salvar da esse erro que tentei de varias formas ao alcance do meu conhecimento resolver e não consegui.

segue o erro:
[image: Erro ao salvar]

Comment: Voce colocou os campos do seu form como "readonly".. De onde vem os dados para preencher esses campos?

Comment: Vem do model CadastroDoPaceinte, eu não tinha pensado que o "readonly" poderia influenciar no auto preenchimento

Comment: Acredito que o readonly nao influencia mesmo.. só queria entender melhor sua questao..
O que voce quer que esse form faça exatamente?
Voce ja tem os dados do "CadastroDoPaceinte" e quer apenas incluir os novos dados da "RegulacaoPaciente"?

Comment: Exatamente, o models "RegulacaoPaciente" vai ser criado com base no "CadastroDoPaceinte", então os campos referente ao cadastro sao iniciados com os dados do cadastro e eu adiciono ao demais campos os dados adicionas, para assim gerar o conteúdo da "RegulacaoPaciente"..

Answer (score 1):

Porque voce nao faz sua model CadastroDoPaceinte assim:?

```
class RegulacaoPaciente(models.Model):

    cadastro_do_paciente = models.ForeignKey(CadastroDoPaciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cadastrarcartaosisreg = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hospital_de_origem = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hospital_de_destino = models.ForeignKey(Hospitais, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vincularlocomocaopaciente = models.ForeignKey(LocoMocaoPaciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reservadeleito = models.CharField(max_length=50)# criar status para em trasito / ocupado
    hospitalarinformarnumeroaih = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tipoveiculousado = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    observacoesgerais = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Ao invés de colocar cada campo do model "CadastroDoPaciente", instancie o objeto inteiro...

Sobre sua pergunta... Quais são os dados novos que voce quer salvar? Quais dados ja existem? Desses dados ja existentes, voce quer alterar algum?
A resposta depende dessas observações

---

Continuando a resposta de acordo com seu comentário..

Se o que voce quer salvar são os dados do model "RegulacaoPaciente", então sua View tem que dizer isso:

```
class Regulacao_do_Pacinete_CreateViews(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView, UpdateView):
    form_class = Regulacao_Do_Paciente_Form
    model = RegulacaoPaciente  # Este model é que terá os dados salvos
    template_name = "principal/regulacao_do_paciente.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

Voce irá criar um novo objeto do model "RegulacaoPaciente", instanciar o objeto (que voce ja tem) do model "CadastroDoPaciente" e colocar esse objeto no novo campo ***cadastro_do_paciente***

Comment: Creio que é isso que estou moscando, realmente não preciso criar os mesmo campos do Cadastro certo? preciso apenas criar um campo pra referencias o cadastro e adicionar os campos novos é isso?

Comment: Acredito que seja isso mesmo.

Comment: Vou refatorar e falo o resultado, muito obrigado pela  ajuda.

Comment: Olá Vinicius Bussola! Você estava certo depois que refiz o model ele esta salvando tudo perfeitinho, mai sai surgiu uma duvida minha, como exibis os campos existentes dentro da foreing Key sem que isso influencie o  formulário?  tentei resgatar utilizando uma query mais da erro poque eu não sei como fazer. estou pesquisando aqui como fazer. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: voce pode fazer algo do tipo: regulacao = RegulacaoPaciente.objects.get(id=1)

nome = regulacao.cadastro_do_paciente.nome....
Se continuar com duvidas, abra outra pergunta